# Pause motion tracking

Tags: unity-game-engine, google-project-tango, tango

I'm using the motion tracking but I would like to "pause" it. The room where I use the app is small, so I would like to pause/stop motion tracking then move (physically) into the center of the room and then restart motion tracking.
I tried to return if the app is paused into "OnTangoPoseAvailable" but the origin of the scene is still at the position where I launched the app.
Is it possible to redifine the origine of the scene ?

(I don't need a code, just the function to use or an idea)
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have not seen anything in the API that allows you to redefine the origin. However, I have had such a need. Here's what I did:

1. Capture a few points to define the users origin. If you don't care about the rotation you could use just one point to redefine the origin.
2. Use those points to translate and rotate pose data to the new coordinate system

The biggest problem being that it depends on the user creating their own origin. Which might be simple for you to visualize but not the end user.